# Asynchronous FIFO cdc question

Tags: fifo, cdc

1) Why there is no multi-bit synchronization problem for slow clock domain ? it is obvious that the pointers could increment by more than one. 
Screenshot from [sunburst asynchronous FIFO paper page 12](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_FIFO1.pdf#page=12)

[image: Section 5.3 Different clock speeds]

2) According to [FIFO depth consideration](http://rtlery.com/components/asynchronous-fifo-synchronizer) , why "The depth of the FIFO is therefore required to be at least 10 cycles, 5 in each direction for updating the pointer" ?

[image: at least 10 cycles]

3) Why is the asynchronous FIFO driven with *wclk* clock from write domain ? and why *rinc* does not "AND" with *!rempty* ?

Screenshot extracted from [sunburst asynchronous FIFO paper page 9](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_FIFO1.pdf#page=9)

[image: FIFO#1]

There is alternative version that does not require the AND gate to generate the signal *wclken*. Could anyone elaborate ?

Screenshot extracted from [sunburst asynchronous FIFO paper page 5](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_FIFO2.pdf#page=5)

[image: FIFO#2]

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Why there is no multi-bit synchronization problem for slow clock domain ?

The point with a gray counter is that if only one bit changes at a time, you can either see the old value or the new value, but never a wrong value.
If we have a fast counter that changes 0001,0011,0010 within one slow clock cycle, the slow reader sees either 0011 or 0010 and calculates a change of 1 or 2, but in any case reads a valid counter value, albeit one clock cycle later or earlier. There is no chance to get a mix-up between the different counter values because the bits change at very different times.

Compare to a regular counter that changes 0110, 0111, 1000 the receiver sees 0111 or 1000, but could also see a 0110 when reading during the switching phase of the counter.

> 2) why "The depth of the FIFO is therefore required to be at least 10 cycles, 5 in each direction for updating the pointer" ?

In principle it is possible to run such a FIFO even with a depth of 1 word only. This will work, but introduces long dead times were no new word can be written to the FIFO: After writing one word, the FIFO is full. The write counter needs update (1 clock cycle) information that one word has been written needs to be transferred to the other clock domain (2-3) and the word has to be read (1). Now this information has to propagate in the opposite direction with the same delay of another 5 clock cycles. This means with our example of a 1-word deep FIFO, one word can be transferred each 10 clock cycles only. To overcome these dead times, the FIFO has to be large enough that it never runs full or empty, which means it has to hold at least 10 words - after the tenth word the input side knows that the very first word has been read and there is again space in the FIFO.

Naturally, this holds only if no side stops writing or reading or the clocks are very different.

> 3) Why is the asynchronous FIFO driven with wclk clock from write domain ?

It looks like this is a FIFO with asynchronous read. If the memory is fully synchronous, the read side has to be read using rclk.

> and why rinc does not "AND" with !rempty ?

This looks like an error to me. Either there needs to be some external logic preventing read-when-empty and write-when-full - or we assume the wptr and rptr boxes do take care about this issue.

Comment: the word has to be read (1)    --> I thought the output after the two/three synchronizers is only of "wire" type, why add another register ?

Comment: "the word" refers to the data in the FIFO, not the write pointer value. And this word has to be cleared from the FIFO before the logic can signal that there is again some free space.    Btw: Note that this delays depend a lot on the actual implementation on the FIFO. With optimizations to the logic you can get down to 8 or even a bit less clock cycles, but there is almost no practical use where it makes sense to add more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a partial answer to one question, but here goes.

```
1) Why there is no multi-bit synchronization problem for slow clock domain ?
```

In the screenshot/link you post, it is said:

```
the first Gray code change will occur well before the rising edge of the
slower clock and only the second Gray code transition could change near
the rising clock edge.
```

I think this is not worded in the clearest possible way.

I also believe that in order for this quote to be correct, there is an implicit assumption that the metastability window of the flipflop on the read clock side is shorter than one clock cycle of the write clock. Also assuming that the all the gray counter bits change at the same time (with very small skew), this means that in one metastability window you will either see one bit or no bits change.

I suspect that both assumptions are reasonable and have maybe been left out by the author because he takes them as givens.

The first assumption, metastability window is smaller than one write clock cycle, is likely to be reasonable. In a given technology, flipflops can have a substantial amount of logic between Q and D on the critical path. Since the flipflops are fast with respect to one clock cycle, their metastability window is likely to fulfil the assumption. Also note that, in contrast to most other relations in clock domain crossing analysis this is not dependent on the ratio of the clocks. Instead it is dependedent on the ratio of write clock and the length of the metastability, a characteristic of the process technology employed to build the flipflop.

The second assumption, little skew between gray code signals, is also likely to be true. At least I find a reference that Vivado does this, see https://forum.digilentinc.com/topic/8809-fifo-cdc-and-gray-codes/. From my own experience, clock domain crossing FIFOs for FPGAs come with their own set of timing constraints. That would be the place to ensure this little skew.